# Running mysqldump on a mysql docker container which is separate to a primary mysql docker container, both sharing the same data via a volume

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use mysqldump to backup the data directory being used by a MySQL docker container.

I am aware of one approach which involves exec'ing onto the MySQL container and running the mysqldump directly on that instance (eg as used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63740465/how-to-execute-mysqldump-command-from-the-host-machine-to-a-mysql-docker-contain)), and that is what I will try next. However, I was initially trying the approach recommended by the MySQL docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html#docker-mysqldump), specifically the following section:

> The following instructions assume that you already have a MySQL Server
> running in a Docker container and, when the container was first
> started, a host directory /path-on-host-machine/datadir/ has been
> mounted onto the server's data directory /var/lib/mysql (see
> bind-mounting a host directory on the data directory of the MySQL
> Server for details), which contains the Unix socket file by which
> mysqldump and mysql can connect to the server. We also assume that,
> after the server has been started, a user with the proper privileges
> (admin in this example) has been created, with which mysqldump can
> access the server. Use the following steps to back up and restore
> MySQL Server data:
>
> Backing up MySQL Server data using mysqldump with Docker:
>
> On the same host where the MySQL Server container is running, start
> another container with an image of MySQL Server to perform a backup
> with the mysqldump utility (see documentation of the utility for its
> functionality, options, and limitations). Provide access to the
> server's data directory by bind mounting
> /path-on-host-machine/datadir/. Also, mount a host directory
> (/path-on-host-machine/backups/ in this example) onto a storage folder
> for backups inside the container (/data/backups is used in this
> example) to persist the backups you are creating. Here is a sample
> command for backing up all databases on the server using this setup:
>
> ```
> $> docker run --entrypoint "/bin/sh" \ 
> --mount type=bind,src=/path-on-host-machine/datadir/,dst=/var/lib/mysql \
> --mount type=bind,src=/path-on-host-machine/backups/,dst=/data/backups \
> --rm container-registry.oracle.com/mysql/community-server:8.0 \
> -c "mysqldump -uadmin --password='password' --all-databases > /data/bac
>
> kups/all-databases.sql"
> ```

I can't copy the instructions exactly because my docker container has its data in a volume (rather than a bind) mount. However I could not see why this would make any difference. I am running two docker containers using docker compose, with the following docker compose file (with irrelevant info removed):

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8.2.0'
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'myDb'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - '3306'
    networks:
      - net1
    volumes:
      - dataVol:/var/lib/mysql:rw

  mysql-backup:
    image: 'mysql:8.2.0'
    entrypoint: mysqldump -u root --password root --databases myDb --add-drop-database > /path/to/a/separate/volume/backup.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    networks:
      - net1
    ports:
      - '3307'
    volumes:
      - dataVol:/var/lib/mysql:rw

volumes:
  dataVol:
    driver: local

networks:
  net1:
    driver: bridge
```

I first then ran (via `docker compose up`) the mysql service (and it works correctly). Whilst that service is running, I then ran the backup job (via `docker compose run`) but it repeatedly gives the error:
`[ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11`

Upon a Google, this appears to occur when two MySQL instances are working with the same data directory which apparently we should never be doing. Eg the MySQL docs here suggest we shouldn't do this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-data-directories.html

So I am now confused because it seems that the MySQL docs are contradicting themselves... Or did I somehow do something different (by using a volume not a bind mount) that is causing my error?

Comment: You don't seem to have told the `mysqldump` process the host name of the database container (`-h mysql`), so it might be trying to dump the database directly from the data directory, which it can't do while the database is running.  If that's what's happening, you don't need to mount the data directory into the dump container either.

Comment: Well I didn't include `-h` because the mysql docs example didn't, which I think implies that it is dumping the database directly from the data directory as you say. But your suggestion does sound like a reasonable alternative approach, thanks.